# Issue with Pandas -> pd.read_excel causes SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, excel

I am having issues with Pandas to read an excel file.  When I run a script including "pd.read_excel", I get the error listed below.  The script is below too.

Script ('file_path_name.xlsx' I would replace with an actual file path name):

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('file_path_name.xlsx')
print(df)

Error:

Exception has occurred: SyntaxError
Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)? (**init**.py, line 1187)
File "/opt/homebrew/DataM/test.py", line 3, in 
df = pd.read_excel('file_path_name.xlsx')
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)? (**init**.py, line 1187)

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling pandas.  That did not help.
If I convert the file to a .csv and then use "pd.read_csv", then it does work.  So the issue seems to be with "pd.read_excel".